# How can i edit my localhost message?

Tags: apache

I am very new at web paging. btw, I try to learn by myself and I set up the php, apache, mysql on my macbook. Then, when I type "localhost" and the web page says "It works!" However, I want to edit those message, so I changed the message instead "It works" on index.html ("/Library/Webserver/Documents") and restarted apache, but it still shows "It works!". Do you have any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First try **ctrl+shift+R** it might be cache is not refreshed properly in browser
if it doesn't work the delete **work** and **temp** folder in apache and then start the server

Comment: it works :)!!! thank you !! However, I am sorry someone pressed the downvote on your post with no reason.... by the way, thanks again!!!!